# Print out all users of a machine in C

Tags: c, linux, printing

I've been searching for hours and can not seem to figure this out. I know how to print put the current user on a machine in C but how do I print out all of the users that exist on the machine using C. (I'm running a linux machine) Help is appreciated! :)

Comment: You could try reading from `/etc/passwd` and printing the token before the first ':' character. But this will give you system users as well, and won't work for ldap users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a UNIX machine, use the [`pwent`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getpwent.3.html) series of functions:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main() {
    struct passwd *p;
    while((p = getpwent())) {
        printf("name: %s\n", p->pw_name);
    }
}
```

This will consult the system's authoritative database of users, which may not necessarily be `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 2):

The users of a machine are listed in /etc/passwd. A good way to filter all 'human' users is to do

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" |cut -d: -f1
```

as the human users usually have a home directory.

Now, for calling it inside C, you may use popen. Take a look at

```
man popen
```

Comment: One should avoid using `popen` if there is an API to do it. In this case, `getpwent/getpwuid` is a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // You can restrict the range of UIDs 
    //   depending on whether you care about system users or real users
    int minUID = 0;
    int maxUID = 10000;
    for (int i = minUID; i < maxUID; ++i)
    {
        struct passwd * p = getpwuid(i);
        if (p != NULL)
            printf("%d : %s\n", i, p->pw_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tested on BSD.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
struct passwd *pwd;

while((pwd = getpwent())!=NULL) {
printf("%s\n",pwd->pw_name);

}
return 0;
}
```